# Merge tag [vision] into [computer-vision]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

From the early questions on the tag [vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vision) it seems to have been created for the topic *vision* in the context of a "project" or "product".

- [Should software development be separated from software design & usability? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303891/should-software-development-be-separated-from-software-design-usability)
- [Defining the Vision Through Business Requirements [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350829/defining-the-vision-through-business-requirements)

but after that, it seems like the tag has been (mis-)used for the topic of Computer Vision [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision). From browsing the questions of [vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vision) and reading the *Related tags* section, it seems like 99% of the questions now are about Computer Vision.

I propose that the tag [vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vision) be merged into [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision).

Comment: Ya, although it would need some cleanup first, based on a quick look it's definitely more than 1% that I would classify as unrelated to CV.

Comment: @DanMašek what other "vision" have you seen? I only found those two linked to be about "product vision" and not seeing questions about other kind of "vision".

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76647578 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/76330462 | https://stackoverflow.com/q/77211779 I'd say is just about image I/O and basic manipulation and human vision, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75874680 is also more of image processing. That was just the first page.

Comment: Some the stuff could be considered remotely related to CV, but I'm not sure if it all should be dumped into one vague category (not that it's not already abused for that, like the countless cases where someone can't load an image or read from a WebCam -- the OpenCV tag also contains piles of trivial crap).

Comment: "it seems to have been created for the topic vision in the context of a "project" or "product"." Well, *that* concept is *clearly* off topic now, so I can't see a problem with the merge.